# Replace regexpr sith superscript in VBA

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word, wildcard

I want to replace all occurences of the expression "\^[0-9]{1,2}" with its supercript version using VBA. I've managed to make a substitution of some private cases as it's shown in the code below. However I still need a general form based on regular expressions.

```
' replace ^1
Dim table As table
For Each table In ActiveDocument.Tables
With table.Range.Find
.ClearFormatting
.Text = "^^1"
With .Replacement
.ClearFormatting
.Font.Superscript = wdToggle
.Text = "1"
End With
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue
End With
 Next table
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Tbl As Word.Table
For Each Tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
  With Tbl.Range.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.Font.Superscript = True
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Text = "^^([0-9]@>)"
    .Replacement.Text = "\1"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
Next Tbl
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The code in the question has a number of issues:

1. In VBA a variable name should never be the same name as an object in any library that's referenced for the project. Don't name an object variable for a `Table` object `table`, for example. VBA is *not* case-sensitive so it will interpret the two names the same, which can cause problems.
2. It's necessary to turn on wildcard matching in the code.
3. The correct way to define a caret `^` for wildcard searches is to double the character: `^^` - putting a backslash in front of it is invalid.
4. When using Replace to apply only formatting, it's not necessary to specify the replacement text.
5. If this should be superscript, then set the property to `True`, not to toggle.
6. *Always* use `wdFindStop` when running VBA code to avoid going into a loop.

My test code:

```
Sub FindAndSuperscript()
    Dim tbl As word.Table

    For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
        With tbl.Range.Find
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = "^^[0-9]{1,2}" 'For systems that use a semicolon as list separator: {1;2}
            With .Replacement
                .ClearFormatting
                .Font.Superscript = True
            End With
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, wrap:=wdFindStop
        End With
    Next tbl
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I should eliminate the caret symbol in the result, so the replacement text should be specified in my case. But I got your idea and really appreciate it.